# Is it possible to get a guest ticket for free?

Tags: cartthrob

I'm using cartthrob to sell tickets for events. For specific ticket types the user should have the possibility to create a guest ticket.

The guest ticket could be used by a user who is already registered or a new user. For me it's something like a cartthrob checkout for another user or a 100% coupon for this special event created after the successful payment.

Does somebody has any idea how to solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That depends when the guest ticket gets added.

**Option1 - adding as a separate item**

Useful if offering as an option on cart page

Using the standard add to cart tag - http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/index.html - you could use the "on_the_fly" parameter to add a product that has no specific entry

**Option2 - adding on the event booking page**

Look at using the Multi add to cart tag - http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/multi_add_to_cart_form/index.html - that allows the customer to pick which items they want.

For the guest ticket you could hard code the values or pull in a channel entry, or use an "on_the_fly" tag. You could also use a custom field in the event channel to show/not show the guest ticket option.